# When Installing the Project I am getting the following Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Error's ,**

```
[Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application E:\10\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\Release
\bson.node]
E:\10\node_modules\connect mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\Release\bson.node]
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

I installed 32bit version: https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7-x86.msi.

Comment: Is mongodb installed?

Comment: first of all thanks @JohnHalbert ,yes I Installed mongodb.

Comment: Well I'm not windows, so I shouldn't answer, but just looking at it it seems like something being passed in place of %1 isn't a binary but is expected to be.  Since bson is mongodb my thought was your mongoose module was trying to connect to the mongo daemon and not finding it.  Is mongodb running?

Comment: yes it is running John